# How to pattern-match on `UploadedFile | UploadedFile[]`

Tags: typescript, file-upload, pattern-matching

I'm trying to implement a file upload with TypeScript, [express-fileupload](https://github.com/richardgirges/express-fileupload) and [body-parser](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html). (I've also successfully installed the corresponding @types).

I'm struggling with converting a JavaScript example to TypeScript, but I think my problem is more general. What I want to use (see code) is `form.mv()` and `form.name`, but the compiler keeps complaining that these members do not exist. Looking at the type of my `form` variable it is a union type of `UploadedFile | UploadedFile[]`, so I think I have to switch depending on the actual type case at runtime. But the compiler doesn't let me pattern-match on the type cases that it actually inferred (see screenshot). What is the right way to handle this type?

Screenshot:

[image]

Complete code:

```typescript
import {Express, Request, Response} from 'express';
import fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
import bodyParser = require('body-parser');
export class Server {
    private app: Express;
    constructor(app: Express) {
        this.app = app;
        this.app.use(fileUpload({createParentPath: true}));
        this.app.use(bodyParser.json());
        this.app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
        this.app.post('/form', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
            try {
                if (!req.files) {
                    res.send({
                        status: false,
                        message: 'No form uploaded'
                    });
                } else {
                    // use the name of the upload field to retrieve the uploaded form
                    let form = req.files.form;
                    // use the mv() method to place the file in the forms directory
                    switch (form) {
                        case fileUpload.UploadedFile: true;
                        case fileUpload.UploadedFile[]: false
                    }
                    form.mv('./forms/' + form.name);
                }
            }
       });
    }
    public start(port: number): void {
        this.app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server listening on port ${port}!`));
    }
}
```

Comment: @wiktor-stribizew I've looked at the description of the `pattern-matching` tag, and it is about data structures and FP, not regular expressions. Why did you remove it?

Answer (score 2):

you can use the The instanceof operator. it is used to check the type of an object at run time.

so your code should look like this

```
if(form instanceof Array){
// code to be executed for array of files
}else{
// code to be executed for one file object
}
```

you can read more about it at
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/instanceof-operator-in-javascript/

Comment: I'm actually hoping for a more Typescript-idiomatic solution, but thanks anyway. This might be something I can resort to.